# Maximum page width a printer can handle

Tags: c#, printing

Is there any way I can interrogate a printer and find the maximum page width that it can take (as seen in printer preferences).

I have an app that is printing images, and sometimes the image I produce is wider than the printer can handle. So I need to know the selected printers maximum page width.

Using the printable area of a page doesn't help me. I need to know the maximum width of page for a printer.

Cheers

Comment: Have you checked this [MSDN PrintCapabilities Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.printing.printcapabilities%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Comment: Hmm, no, you need to know the paper size, not the maximum width the printer can handle.  Printing outside of the paper bounds is not useful.